# Is G isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $ G=\{3^{m}6^{n}|m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ under multiplication then i want prove that this G 
is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.Can any one help me to solve this example?
please help me. thanks in advance.

Can i define $\phi:\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} to G$ 
as $\phi\big((m,n)\big)=3^m 6^n$

Comment: Find some generators of $G$; find some generators of the other group; see what happens when you map the one set to the other.

Comment: but $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is not cylic.if i take (a,b) then (a,b+1) is not there.similarly if i take (a,b+1) then i can't get (a,b). so it is not cylci.

Comment: Speaking of "generators" does not mean we assume a group is cyclic. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas in G $2$ is genrator?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi 2 is _not_ a generator - 3, which is in $G$, is not in the group generated by 2 under multiplication.  Indeed, there's no single generator for $G$, so it doesn't make sense to be referring to any given element as a generator; instead pick a _pair_ of elements and ask if they generate the set.

Comment: The map $\phi$ you defined is obviously injective and surjective...alternatively $G$ is the subgroup $3\mathbf{Z} \times 6\mathbf{Z} \subset \mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In order to find an isomorphism, you need to find two generators $g_1, g_2$ of $G$ that correspond to $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ from $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. This means that every element of $G$ can be uniquely expressed as $g_1^i g_2^j$.

Comment: here in $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ i have to generator how to find generators in G?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi Look to the prime factorization of elements in $G$.

Comment: in G $2$ is genrator?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $2^k=3^{-k}6^k$.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Any integer.${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi: If someone does not give a solution, I will after a long delay. The two hints you have been given may be enough for you to produce your own answer, which is much better for your mathematical development.

Comment: The number $k$ ranges over the integers. so does the first coordinate of an arbitrary member of the direct sum. OK, so this was a third hint.

Comment: @anon: Thanks, I do have typing (or attention) problems.

Comment: thanks for edit i was confused.now i get both side equal.

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi: Apologies for the typo! It is $2^k=3^{-k}6^k$.

Comment: Sure, sum of any two elements of the group is an element of the group.

Comment: Is there two generator or three genterator in $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is $(1,1)$ is the third generator?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8610/discussion-between-siddhant-trivedi-and-andre-nicolas)